# android: how to make the method synchronized

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to figure out this problem for a long time, and perhaps it is caused by multithreading. I am a beginner so I am not able to work it out. Please help me~

I use a cloud database called "bmob", and I found that I can successfully get the data I want. However, there might be some mistakes in the loops, and I could only get the information of the last selected item.

p.s. I use an array list called Playlist to store the calculated data that I will use to display a list-view in the next activity.

here is my code:

```
public class DestinationActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {

//textviews.....

private List<Destination> destinationList = new ArrayList<Destination>();


private DestinationAdapter adapter;
//I have successfully set up the list view

//some int and double values 


//to store the id the user selects
private ArrayList<Integer> select_placeID = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
public Map<Integer,Double> weightMap;
public List<Plan> planList = new ArrayList<Plan>();
int[] selectedID = new int[10];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.destination_layout);

    //initialize the cloud database
    Bmob.initialize(this, BmobConfig.APP_ID);

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_destination);

destinationOk_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);


initDestinations(); // initialize the data


adapter = new DestinationAdapter(destinationList, DestinationActivity.this);
//adapter = new DestinationAdapter(this, destinationList, DestinationAdapter.getIsSelected());
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//....listeners and textviews.......

//submit button
destinationOk_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        select_placeID.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < destinationList.size(); i++) {
            if (DestinationAdapter.getIsSelected().get(i)) {
                select_placeID.add((i + 1));
            }

        }

        //change to int array
        selectedID = new int[select_placeID.size()];
        for(int i = 0;i<select_placeID.size();i++){
            selectedID[i] = select_placeID.get(i);
        }

        if (select_placeID.size() == 0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(DestinationActivity.this);
            builder1.setMessage("no records");
            builder1.show();
        }

else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DestinationActivity.this);

            builder.setMessage("waiting for magic...");
            builder.show();

            /**
             * calculate the route
             */
            if (validate()) {
                new calRoute().execute();//switch to a new thread
            }


        }
    }

    });
}



//initialize the data
private void initDestinations() {
    //........
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //.......
}


/**
 * asynctask
 */
private class calRoute extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Plan>>{


public calRoute(){
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
protected List<Plan> doInBackground(Void... params) {

    List<Plan> result = calculate(time_start, time_end, travel_days);

    return result;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Plan> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (result != null) {
        Toast.makeText(DestinationActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(planList.size() > 0) {


            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(DestinationActivity.this, ActivityPlan.class);

            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("planInfo", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) planList);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

        else{
            Toast.makeText(DestinationActivity.this, "no plan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
}


/**
 *plan
 **/
public List<Plan> calculate(String time_start, String time_end, int    travel_days) {


    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(("HH:mm"));

Date starttime = new Date();
Date endtime = new Date();
try {
    starttime = df.parse(time_start);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    endtime = df.parse(time_end);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

double l = endtime.getTime() - starttime.getTime();
double hour = (l / (60 * 60 * 1000));
double min = ((l / (60 * 1000)) - hour * 60);

if(min == 0){
    min = 60;
}
else {
    travel_time = ((1.0 * travel_days * hour) * (min / 60)); 
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    travelTime = Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(travel_time));
}


weightMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double>(); //store weight
int totalPriority = 0;//total priority

final Destination start = new Destination(116.32133, 39.92269);


final HashMap<Integer, Integer> pMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
final HashMap<Integer, String> nameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
final HashMap<Integer, Destination> objectMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Destination>();
    /**
     * get the data from cloud database
     */
            BmobQuery<Destination> query = new BmobQuery<Destination>();
        for (int sid: selectedID) {

            query.addWhereEqualTo("id", sid);


            query.findObjects(new FindListener<Destination>() {

                @Override
                public void done(List<Destination> list, BmobException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        System.out.println("success：total" + list.size() + "items。");
                        for (Destination destination : list) {


                            int p = destination.getPriority();

                            int id = destination.getId();

                            String name = destination.getName();

                            double longitude = destination.getLongitude();
                            double latitude = destination.getLatitude();

                            objectMap.put(id, new Destination(longitude, latitude));

                            System.out.println(id);


                            double dis = DistanceUtil.distance(start.getLongitude(), start.getLatitude(),
                                    longitude, latitude);

                            pMap.put(id, p);
                            weightMap.put(id, new Double(dis));
                            nameMap.put(id, name);

                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i("bmob", "error：" + e.getMessage() + "," + e.getErrorCode());
                    }
                }
            });
        }


for (Integer key : pMap.keySet()) {
    int p = pMap.get(key).intValue();
    totalPriority = totalPriority + p;
}


double weight = 0.0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> hm : weightMap.entrySet()) {
    double hm2Value = pMap.get(hm.getKey());
    weight = totalPriority / hm.getValue() * hm2Value;

    weightMap.put(hm.getKey(), weight);
}


/**
 * 按照weight值来排序
 * 判断是否传递数据给plan_activity
 */
MapUtil.sortByValue(weightMap);

//排好序后计算距离
Iterator it = weightMap.entrySet().iterator();
int order = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    order++;
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    objectMap.put(new Integer(order), objectMap.get(entry.getKey()));
}


PlanTask planTask = new PlanTask();//封装了每个plan计算的方法


for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : weightMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("id= " + entry.getKey());


    double play_time = planTask.calPlay_time(weightMap.size(),
            weightMap.get(entry.getKey()), travelTime);

    double driving_time = planTask.calDrive_time(DistanceUtil.distance(
            objectMap.get(entry.getKey()).getLatitude(),
            objectMap.get(entry.getKey()).getLongitude(),
            objectMap.get(entry.getKey() + 1).getLatitude(),
            objectMap.get(entry.getKey() + 1).getLongitude()
    ));

    String arrive_time = "hello world";//未完待续

    String place_name = nameMap.get(entry.getKey());

    Plan plan = new Plan(place_name, arrive_time, driving_time, play_time);

    //传递plan对象list
    planList.add(entry.getKey(), plan);
    }

    return planList;

}
}
```

When I debug it, I found that in calculate() functions, the output of

```
  BmobQuery<Destination> query = new BmobQuery<Destination>();
             for (int sid: selectedID) {

    query.addWhereEqualTo("id", sid);


   query.findObjects(new FindListener<Destination>() {

                @Override
   public void done(List<Destination> list, BmobException e) {
         if (e == null) {
         System.out.println("success：total" + list.size() + "items。");
         for (Destination destination : list) {

              int p = destination.getPriority();

              int id = destination.getId();

              String name = destination.getName();


              double longitude = destination.getLongitude();
              double latitude = destination.getLatitude();

              objectMap.put(id, new Destination(longitude, latitude));

               System.out.println(id);

               //calculate the distance
              double dis = DistanceUtil.distance(start.getLongitude(), start.getLatitude(),longitude, latitude);

                pMap.put(id, p);
                weightMap.put(id, new Double(dis));
                nameMap.put(id, name);

             }
      } else {
           Log.i("bmob", "error：" + e.getMessage() + "," +  e.getErrorCode());
                    }
                }
            });
```

is "success：total 1 items." and after the loop, if I have selected 3 items, it would be "success：total 1 items." for 3 times and only the information of the last item is caught. AND the size of three hash map: pMap, nameMap and objectMap are all zero. 
Why is it??? It is so strange...please help me to find out what's wrong

p.s. The method findObject() and done() is written by the cloud database platform, I want to ensure that after executing these two methods: I will get the data to be put into the hash-maps, so that the hash maps would not be empty. But I don't know how to synchronize the code.

There is no error in LogCAT, however, the ordered list view cannot display in the second activity. PLEASE help me, it has bothered me for a long time. Thank you!!!

Comment: can you align your code properly. it seems like disgusting.

Comment: Alright, so the problem is you are getting empty `planList` in `ActivityPlan` activity. Right?

Comment: yeah! and it is caused by empty hash maps: pMap, nameMap and objectMap are all zero. Someone told me that he thinks the problem is that done() method is asynchronous so after the loop the size is 0 because done execution is not finished yet so the size of all maps is 0. I want to make the call to query.findObjects() synchronous so I could know it's done before continuing execution, but this method is written by cloud platform so that I cannot alter that. what can I do? please help me~